# Search device contact directory for contact details in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on a project and want to access the contact directory on my device to get a contact detail then return back to the react native app. I have tried `npm I react-native-contacts` and it works fine but it returns an array of the contact which means I have to design a view for it... but what I want is to access the device contact directory itself and select from the contact list then return the selected contact back to react native app. Please how can I achieve this?

Comment: if there is no pacakge that dose what you want, either youll have to design a view for it. Or, find some native code on the web and link it , i suggest you go with the first option

Comment: dose this answer your quetion? https://github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts#open-contact-form

Comment: After some research this worked for me `npm install react-native-contacts-wrapper --save` . I could access the native contact directory and get a contact detail that was return to my react native app...

Answer (score 0):

After some research, this worked for me `npm i react-native-select-contact` . I could access the native contact directory and get a contact detail that was return to my react native app.